# Updating Multiple Selected rows in DGV in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a `DataBound` `DGV` it has 3 `Columns` namely `ID(not pk)`, `Name`, and `Status`. I have 2 Buttons `Add` and `Post`. Add, adds `Data` to the `DGV` and `DataBase(MySql)` but in `Status`, it adds `"No"`. What I want to do is for example I have 3 `Rows` in my  `DGV` and highlight those 3 and click `Post`, the value in `Status` will be changed to `"Yes"`. Here is what I have done so far, but I'm having trouble with the syntax for the `UPDATE QUERY`. **THIS CODE WORKS NOW**

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the TestDataSet.testing table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TestingTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TestDataSet.testing)
        Using _conn As New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; Username= root; Password =; Database = test")

            Using cmd
                With cmd
                    MsgBox("Connection Established")
                    .Connection = _conn
                    .Parameters.Clear()
                    .CommandText = "Select Max(TransactionID) from testing"
                    _conn.Open()
                    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    If dr.Read() Then
                        If IsDBNull(dr.Item(0)) Then
                            txtNumber.Text = "1"
                        Else

                            txtName.Text = dr(0).ToString() + 1
                        End If

                    End If
                End With
            End Using
        End Using

        FillGrid()

    End Sub

    Private Sub FillGrid()



        Using _conn As New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; Username= root; Password =; Database = test")
            Using _comm As New MySqlCommand
                With _comm
                    .CommandText = " SELECT `ID`, `TransactionID`, `Name`, `Posted` FROM `testing`"
                    .Connection = _conn
                End With
                Using _adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(_comm)
                    Try
                        _conn.Open()
                        Dim _ds As New DataSet
                        _adapter.Fill(_ds)
                        GVTransaction.DataSource = _ds.Tables(0)
                    Catch ex As Exception

                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; Username= root; Password =; Database = test")
            Using cmd
                With cmd
                    MsgBox("Connection Established")
                    .Connection = conn
                    .Parameters.Clear()
                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO testing(TransactionID, Name, Posted) VALUES (@ID, @iName, @iPosted)"
                    .Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@ID", txtNumber.Text))
                    .Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@iName", txtName.Text))
                    .Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@iPosted", "No"))


                End With
                Try
                    conn.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As MySqlException
                    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using

        MsgBox("Data Added to the Database")

        Me.TestingTableAdapter.Dispose()

        Me.TestingTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TestDataSet.testing)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPost_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPost.Click


        Dim _ID As New List(Of String)
        Dim _Name As New List(Of String)
        For Each _x As DataGridViewRow In TestingDataGridView.SelectedRows
            _ID.Add(_x.Cells("GVTransactionID").Value.ToString())
            _Name.Add("'" & _x.Cells("GVName").Value.ToString() & "'")
        Next
        Dim inClause As String = String.Join(",", _ID.ToArray())
        Dim inClause1 As String = String.Join(",", _Name.ToArray())
        Dim _sqlUpdate As String = String.Format("UPDATE testing SET Posted = @Posted WHERE TransactionID IN ({0}) AND Name IN ({1})", inClause, inClause1)

        Using _conn As New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; Username= root; Password =; Database = test")
            Using _commm As New MySqlCommand()
                With _commm
                    .CommandText = _sqlUpdate
                    .Connection = _conn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Posted", "YES")

                End With
                Try
                    _conn.Open()
                    _commm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    FillGrid()
                Catch ex As MySqlException
                    MsgBox(ex.StackTrace.ToString)
                End Try

            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any Helps or tips is greatly appreciated. Please and Thank you

Comment: I am now able to change column `Status` from "no" to "Yes" the problem is everything in the `status` column is being changed, even if it's not Highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one,

```
Dim _ID As New List(Of String) 
Dim _Name As New List(Of String) 
For Each _x As DataGridViewRow In TestingDataGridView.SelectedRows  
   _ID.Add(_x.Cells("TransactionID").Value.ToString())
   _Name.Add("'" & _x.Cells("Name").Value.ToString() & "'")
Next 

Dim inClause As String = String.Join(",", _ID.ToArray()) 
Dim inClause1 As String = String.Join(",", _Name.ToArray()) 
Dim _sqlUpdate As String = String.Format("UPDATE testing SET Posted = @Posted WHERE TransactionID IN ({0}) AND Name IN ({1})", inClause, inClause1)

Using _conn As New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; Username= root; Password =; Database = test")
    Using _comm As New MySqlCommand()
        With _comm
          .CommandText = _sqlUpdate
          .Connection = _conn
        End With
        Try
            _conn.Open()
            _comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try

    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I'm using vb.net, isn't this for C#? if it's ok would you help me use this for .NET? thanks

Comment: I get this exception Column named ID cannot be found.
Parameter name: columnName
at  this line  _ID.Add(_x.Cells("ID").Value.ToString())
why is that?

Comment: replace `ID` to the name of your data column or if the ID is on the first index change it to, `_x.Cells(0).Value.ToString()`

Comment: I tried changing it to_ID.Add(_x.Cells(0).Value.ToString()) but now I get fatal error in command execution.

Comment: what is the name of your data column for your ID?

Comment: `TransactionID` Im really sorry for the late reply, We we're asked to go out.

Comment: does this work?`_ID.Add(_x.Cells("TransactionID").Value.ToString())`

Comment: back to the argument exception that says Column "TransactionID" could not be found. I wonder what's causing this.

Comment: may I ask something again. is it okay if you could put comments on the code so I could study them, and also try to figure it out. that would be very helpful. Thanks :D

Comment: Please don't give up on this, I just really need help. Please and Thank You

Comment: add this code,Dim _ID As New List(Of String) 
Dim _Name As New List(Of String) 
For Each _x As DataGridViewRow In TestingDataGridView.SelectedRows 
_ID.Add(_x.Cells("TransactionID").Value.ToString()); 
_Name.Add("'" & _x.Cells("Name").Value.ToString() & "'"); 
Next 


Dim inClause As String = String.Join(",", _ID.ToArray()) 
Dim inClause1 As String = String.Join(",", _Name.ToArray()) 
Dim _sqlUpdate As String = String.Format("UPDATE testing SET Posted = @Posted WHERE TransactionID IN ({0}) AND Name IN ({1})", inClause, inClause1)

Comment: hmm, I don't know how to add codes in the comment but let me show you the full codes... It's working now, Thank you so much.!I just have to figure out how to do it without having to create a new DGV. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hahah your update made the command execution error again. let me post the one that works, and see for yourself :)

Comment: I updated the codes on my question, that works, but I need to have only 1 DGV, without having to create a new one. I'm trying to fix that now. :)

Comment: @AlexLuthor sorry, forgot to add `parameters`, you can just delete the other DGV. (*the one I created. it's a sample hehe*)

Comment: got another problem. when I add this 2 lines    `Me.TestingTableAdapter.Dispose()`
`Me.TestingTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TestDataSet.testing)`

the post button works but it goes back to changing everything (Even un selected rows) `"No"` to `"Yes"` . Why?

Comment: Ohh nevermind, it was a glitch, Thank you so much for helping me and for your efforts, I hope to be better with programming like you are soon :D

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply use this

```
For Each Row As DataGridViewRow In TestingDataGridView.SelectedRows
   .CommandText = "UPDATE testing SET Posted = @iChange WHERE ID = " & Row.Cells(0) & ", Name = " & Row.Cells(1)
   .CommandType = CommandType.Text
   .Parameters.AddWithValue("@iChange", "Yes")
End For
```

Hope this helps :)